# Print two points with mpf.plot mplfinance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, mplfinance

I would like to print out some Pivot Points in a chart. But I have trouble with time variables.

```
two_points =[(lastDate,lastPivot),(yesterday,lastPivot)]
mpf= mpf.plot(dfnew_plot,type='candle',alines= two_points)
```

But the time variable lastDate and yesterday do not have the same format:
lastDate =
2021-01-15 00:00:00
yesterday=
2021-01-30

> lastDate =
> 2021-01-15 00:00:00
> yesterday= 2021-01-30

How can I format lastDate and yesterday correct?

The end result plot is the following. Actualy sometimes the code is working and sometimes not:

```
mpf.plot(dfnew_plot,volume=True,style='starsandstripes',datetime_format=' %d-%m',alines= 
two_points,addplot=apdict\
,xrotation=45,title=(stock),type='candle',\
ylabel='ROC5= '+(ROC5) +' ' +'ROC20= '+(ROC20)+ ' ' +'ROCmean= '+(ROCmean),figscale=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what data type your points are.  (This makes a difference as to what the simplest way to handle them to alines).  please print out `type(lastDate)` and `type(yesterday)` (_It would also be helpful to show the code from where you get these two_.)  If they were both coming from the dataframe.index they should be the same type.  Also would be helpful to show the full exception and traceback you are getting from `mpf.plot()` when attempting to pass `two_points`.

Comment: The problem was on weekends. The variable yesterday was bigger than the last index date. Therefore the last plotting date (lastDate) was smaller then the date (yesterday). Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Thanks.  As point out in the comment above, and in general when reporting an error "Also would be helpful to show the full exception and traceback you are getting ..."   In this case I think the exception would have indicated that the dates were out of order.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on weekends. The variable yesterday was bigger than the last index date. Therefore the last plotting date (lastDate) was smaller then the date (yesterday). Thanks a lot for your support.